# Как индексировать в поисковых системах html-разметку хранящуюся в БД?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, django, postgresql, поисковые-системы

Есть проект на Django с Postgresql и хочется попробовать хранить html-разметку в БД, а при обращении по определённой ссылке открывать её. Это сделать не проблема, но встаёт вопрос индексации поисковиками. Как сделать чтобы поисковики индекировали эти html-разметки в БД?

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Если у вас ссылка с нужным контентом открывается - её сможет открыть и поисковик, БД вообще ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal проблема в том, что ссылка является параметрической. Т.е. число 2018 в сылке news/2018/ показывает все новости за 2018 год. Я понимаю, что если ссылка с нужным контекстом открывается, то её сможет открыть и поисковик, но как поисковик узнает о существовании ссылки /news/2018, если я не буду ни где её размещать?

Comment: А как о ссылке узнает хоть кто-нибудь, если вы не будете её нигде размещать? :)

Answer (score 0):

Генерируете в корне сайта файл sitemap.xml со списком доступных ссылок для индексации.
Правила генерации и примеры можно посмотреть тут https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077#sitemap